# Copy last word from the line above the cursor?

Tags: tmux

I recently discovered <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> shortcut in Bash and it boosted my productivity greatly. It lets me copy the last argument I used in the previous command I ran. Now I'd love to see something like this, but for the output of those commands ran under tmux. Is there an easy way to create a shortcut that would figure out where my cursor is (it's likely a shell prompt), go one line above and copy the last word on that line?

In other words, imagine I'm running tmux with the example state of the terminal:

```
d33tah@d33tah-pc:/home/d33tah(0) > aws s3 ls s3://tmp-somethingsomething
2022-10-27 13:23:27  242391549 3ac38f9cdd90a1ef6561a11bd171110a.json.gz
d33tah@d33tah-pc:/home/d33tah(0) >
```

In that case the command would automatically type in `3ac38f9cdd90a1ef6561a11bd171110a.json.gz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example. You can update it per your requirements.

First, create a script, e.g. `~/tmp/tmux.sh`:

```
tmux copy-mode
tmux send -X cursor-up
line=$( tmux display -p -F '#{copy_cursor_line}' )
sth=$( echo -- "$line" | awk '{ print $NF }' )
tmux send -X cancel
tmux send -l -- "$sth"
```

Then, define key binding in your tmux conf like this:

```
bind z run 'bash ~/tmp/tmux.sh'
```

Comment: Thank you! And to bind this new superpower to `Alt+,`, we can do `bind-key -n M-, run 'bash ~/tmp/tmux.sh'`